# Transitive set not ordered by epsilon

Tags: set-theory

My question is as described in the title.

Say I have a four element set that is transitive but not ordered by epsilon.

Transitive sets are such that all elements of the set are subsets of that set.
Sets ordered by epsilon are such that for any 2 elements x, y of set A, x ∈ y or x = y or y ∈ x.

What would this set look like? I am struggling to think of an example.

Answer (score 1):

$\{∅,\{∅\},\{\{∅\}\}\}$ is an example. $\emptyset$ is in the collection, but $\emptyset \notin \{\{\emptyset\}\}$. A quick manual calculation will prove that this set is also transitive.

Comment: maybe you should add one more, she asked for a four element set.

Comment: thanks so much. To ensure I'm understanding these concepts correctly: would {0, 1, 2, 3} be an example of a set that is transitive and ordered by epsilon?

Comment: Yes, that would be.

Comment: @Laassilasouhayl Sure. Simply append the element $\{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ to the set I provided.

Comment: @DuncanRamage how is {0,1,2,3} even a transitive set ?

Comment: @Laassilasouhayl Using the standard construction of the ordinals, $0 = \emptyset$, $1 = \{0\}$, $2 = \{0, 1\}$, and $3 = \{0, 1, 2\}$.

Comment: @DuncanRamage thank you